# Одна или две буквы Н?

Tags: удвоенные-буквы, суффиксы-прилагательных

Наиболее ёмко и концентрирова(?)о воплощение царя-труженика представлено Ломоносовым.

Сколько букв Н тут пишется и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пишутся две буквы НН: Наиболее ёмко и **концентрированно** воплощение царя-труженика представлено Ломоносовым.

Схема образования: Концентрировать - концентрирова**нн**/ый (прилаг.) - концентрирова**нн**/о (наречие). **Наречие сохраняет форму отглагольного прилагательного.**

**Пояснение**

От глагола "концентрировать"  образуется форма "концентрированный", в которой при наличии суффикса ИРОВА всегда пишутся две буквы НН (формальный признак). Так как глагол **несов. вида**, то эта форма обычно является **прилагательным** (причастием она становится при наличии зависимых слов).

Причастие образуется от глагола "сконцентрировать" (сов. вид): сконцентрированный (**две буквы НН**) - сконцентрирована  (краткое причастие, **одна буква Н**).

**КОНЦЕНТРИРОВАТЬ,**  концентрированный;  1. (св. сконцентрировать). Собирать, скапливать в каком-л. месте всех, многих или всё, многое. К. войска. К. все силы для главного удара. 2. (св. сконцентрировать). на чём. Направлять, устремлять на что-л. одно; сосредоточивать (мысли, внимание, интересы и т.п.). Научиться к. внимание.  И т.д.

Comment: Завизировано...

Comment: Завизировать (сов. вид) - завизированный (причастие) - завизировано (краткое причастие)

Comment: >> *...в которой при наличии суффикса ИРОВА всегда пишутся две буквы НН (формальный признак)*

Comment: Вы можете назвать ПОЛНУЮ глагольную форму с суффиксом на ОВА  (прилагательное или причастие),  в которой пишется одна буква Н?